# How to run a ruby script by using chef with rbenv?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, rbenv

I want to run a ruby script by chef's `execute` resource like this.

```
execute "my_prog deamon" do
  command  %Q{bash -c 'export PATH="/usr/local/rbenv/bin:$PATH"; eval "$(rbenv init -)"; cd /opt/my_prog; ruby /opt/my_prog/my_prog_deamon.rb start'}
end
```

And I got error message like this.

```
---- Begin output of bash -c 'export PATH="/usr/local/rbenv/bin:$PATH"; eval "$(rbenv init -)"; cd /opt/my_prog; ruby /opt/my_prog/my_prog_deamon.rb start' ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- daemons (LoadError)
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /opt/my_prog/my_prog_deamon.rb:2:in `<main>'
---- End output of bash -c 'export PATH="/usr/local/rbenv/bin:$PATH"; eval "$(rbenv init -)"; cd /opt/my_prog; ruby /opt/my_prog/my_prog_deamon.rb start' ----
```

It looks like the error happens because ruby from `chef` is called instead of ruby from `rbenv`.

I rewrote `ruby` to `/usr/local/rbenv/shims/ruby` in recipe, but I got same error.

How can I run a ruby script by using chef? The `rbenv` is installed system wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be originating from your custom script, with the error indicating that a requirement (in this case, the [daemons gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/daemons)) cannot be loaded.

Either the ruby version you are using hasn't installed the correct dependencies, or the `$GEM_PATH` is incorrect and thus it can't find the required dependencies.

If you only run this script from your Chef recipes, I would recommend looking at the [resource_script](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_script.html) provider, provided by Chef by default, in your case specifically the **[resource_ruby](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_ruby.html)** provider:

```
ruby 'my_prog_deamon' do
  ...
end
```

If this isn't an option, I would run the script through the Chef ruby, and use `chef_gem` to install the required dependencies:

```
chef_gem('daemons') do
  version 'x.y.z'
end
```

Then, when calling the script with the Chef gem, you can be sure the dependency is installed.

Answer (score 0):

> I rewrote ruby to /usr/local/rbenv/shims/ruby in recipe, but I got same error.

Since the shim itself is pointing to Chef's Ruby, most likely rbenv was not configured correctly. If rbenv can't find a version configuration it will just direct you to the first ruby it finds.

Check that you've specified your desired version using one of these methods:

https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#choosing-the-ruby-version